# ¿error al recibir un valor bool en .net core?

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core

Tengo mi formulario con un select el cual tiene el nombre de status.

```
<select id="status" name="status" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Activo</option>
    <option value="0">Inactivo</option>
</select>
```

al momento de recibirlo en mi controlador en el objeto status siempre llega un false(0), y en mi clase la propiedad de estatus es un bool.

```
public IActionResult Nuevo(Tblusuario tblusuario)
    return view();
}
```

modelo:

```
    public class Tblusuario{
       [Key]
        public int Id{get; set;}
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string clave {get; set;}
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string nombre{get; set;}
        [StringLength(150)]
        public string descripcion{get; set;}
        public bool status {get; set;}
    }
```

¿Cómo puedo resolverlo sin cambiar la propiedad status a int?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que ese código funciona? En el controlador hace falta especificar qué es tblusuario.

Comment: Perdón, efectivamente el modelo es tblUsuario y la instancia es "x" o "usuario" como lo quieres ver. saludos.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, coloca todo lo que haga falta para reproducir tu escenario. Incluido el modelo junto con sus propiedades

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quiere que `model binding` mapee un `bool` podrias usar

```
<select id="status" name="status" class="form-control">
    <option value="true">Activo</option>
    <option value="false">Inactivo</option>
</select>
```

al poner true/false

Sino va a tener que craer un `custom model binding`

[Custom Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Si me funciono, muchas gracias.